# How to add a superscript while plotting a measurement unit in R?

Tags: r

I wish to add a label: `kgC/m^2/month` to y axis of a plot in R with `^2` being displayed as superscript on `m`.

Comment: Also see `?plotmath`, and take a look at `demo(plotmath)` to see the variety of mathematical symbols you can plot using the approach @Benjamin has described below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plot(..., ylab = expression(kgC/m^2/month) )
```

You may also want to try `frac` for fractions (but this doesn't always work great for axis labels)

```
plot(..., main = expression( frac(kgC,m^2)/month) )
```

Additionally, use `?plotmath` to visit help on mathematical annotations or `demo(plotmath)` to run through a series of examples that demonstrate the source and output for many common mathematical expressions.

Comment: You could include the information where help for plotting mathematical notation can be found (@Josh O'Brien's comment) to make the answer a little bit more complete.

Comment: @Ben sorry about that--didn't mean to be rude.