# Add superscript to lattice graph labels R

Tags: r, lattice

I need to add superscript to my R lattice graph labels, specifically with "m^2".

```
equivalence.xyplot(mydata$IsoCanopyArea ~ mydata$ControlCanopyArea,
                   alpha=0.05, b0.ii=0.25, b1.ii=0.25,
                   xlab= "ISODATA (m^2)",
                   ylab= "Measured (m^2)")
```

This function uses lattice graphics, so the typical commands do not seem to work:

```
plot(0, ylab = ~ "AddTextHere" (m^2))
```

I have looked at several examples on this site with no success: [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10628662/1446289) and [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9507009/1446289) (*Note* I am a different Aaron than the OP in example2)

How can accomplish superscripts in lattice graph labels?

Comment: Typically axis labels should be supplied as characters, expressions or something else that can be converted to a character or an expression. However, `~"AddTextHere" (m^2))` creates an object of class `formula`. My guess is that the standard `plot` function automatically converts it to an expression, but `xyplot` does not and just ignore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `expression` as in:

```
plot(...
    xlab=expression("ISODATA " (m^2))
    ylab= expression("Measured" (m^2))
....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the solution from @Jilber, the following changes to the graph worked:

```
equivalence.xyplot(mydata$IsoCanopyArea ~ mydata$ControlCanopyArea,
                   alpha=0.05, b0.ii=0.25, b1.ii=0.25,
                   xlab= expression("ISODATA " (m^2)),
                   ylab= expression("Measured " (m^2)))
```

[image]